# Getting outlook signature details using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, signature

I’m working on a project that needs to accessing outlook’s signature setting using C#. Usually you can enable and disable the signature setting, Is there a way to access and read the outlook’s settings from my project? Example see if it the signature is enabled or disable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. You can find the signatures in the following folder. The actual path depends on the user name:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

There look for the following files and folders;

- `<signature_name>.htm` - This file is used when creating HTML messages.
- `<signature_name>.rtf` - This file is used when creating Rich Text messages.
- `<signature_name>.txt` - This file is used when creating Plain Text message.
- `<signature_name>_files` - This folder is used to store supporting files for your signature such as formatting, images and/or business cards (vcf-files).

Comment: Keep in mind that "Signatures" folder name is localized. The localized value is stored in the `Signatures` value in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>.0\Common\General`